# Save django forms on button click

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am currently trying to learn django. I decided to create a small app. currently I am making a form to create VoteType and Voting candidates on one page. I created a page where u can add as many candidate fields as you want, but when I click the button nothing happenes and even if I don't click the button some data is saved. I was watching this django guide on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfjhLKL-_5Q). This guy is making one simple form. He added method = POST and action = '' to  ...  and in views he used (request.POST or None). I tried to do the similar, but as my form is a bit more complicated I got really confused.

so this is my views.py code:

```
def create(request):
    voteTypeForm = VoteTypeForm(request.POST or None)
    voteForm = VoteForm(request.POST or None)
    instance = voteTypeForm.save(commit=False)
    instance.pub_date = timezone.now()
    instance.save()
    instance2 = voteForm.save(commit=False)
    instance2.save()
    #print instance.pub_date
    context = RequestContext(request,{
            'voteTypeForm': voteTypeForm,
            'voteForm': voteForm,
    })
    return render(request, 'Vote/create.html', context)
```

and this is my create.html django template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Vote/style.css' %}" />
<fieldset id="fieldset">
    <form method = 'POST' action = ''>{%csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ voteTypeForm }}</p>
    </form>
        <div id="placeholder">

        </div>
        <p>
            <button type="button" name="Submit" onclick="Add();">+</button>
        </p>
    <input type = 'submit' value="create"/>
</fieldset>
<script type='text/javascript'>
{#    document.write(code);#}
    var _counter = 0;
    var template = document.createTextNode('')
    function appendStringAsNodes(element, html) {
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            tmp = document.createElement('body'), child;
        tmp.innerHTML = html;
        // Append elements in a loop to a DocumentFragment, so that the browser does
        // not re-render the document for each node
        while (child = tmp.firstChild) {
            frag.appendChild(child);
        }
        element.appendChild(frag); // Now, append all elements at once
        frag = tmp = null;
    }
    function Add() {
        var code = '<div id="template">' +
                '<p>' +
                    '<fieldset id="fieldsets">' +
                        '<legend id="legends">Candidate No ['+ String(_counter+1) +']</legend>' +
                       ' <form method = "POST" action = "">'+
                              '<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{csrf_token }}" />' +
                            '<p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input id="id_name" maxlength="50" name="name" type="text" /></p>'+
                            '<p><label for="id_image">Image:</label> <input id="id_image" name="image" type="file" /></p>'+
                        '</form>' +
                   ' </fieldset>' +
                '</p>' +
            '</div>';
        _counter++;
        appendStringAsNodes(document.getElementById("placeholder"),code);
        document.getElementById("someInput").value = _counter;
    }
</script>
```

**how do I fix this code so that my program only saves instances when I push the create button?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to check that the action is a POST, and that the forms are valid, and you must redirect after a successful submission.

```
def create(request):
    voteTypeForm = VoteTypeForm(request.POST or None)
    voteForm = VoteForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check validity separately to avoid short-cutting
        vote_type_valid = voteTypeForm.is_valid()
        vote_form_valid = voteForm.is_valid()
        if vote_type_valid and vote_form_valid:
            instance = voteTypeForm.save(commit=False)
            instance.pub_date = timezone.now()
            instance.save()
            instance2 = voteForm.save(commit=False)
            instance2.save()
            return redirect('<view-you-redirect-to-on-success'>
    context = RequestContext(request,{
            'voteTypeForm': voteTypeForm,
            'voteForm': voteForm,
    })
    return render(request, 'Vote/create.html', context)
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't redirect to another view

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BVMeSvYZ this is what I did. But create button doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Your placeholder div and submit buttons aren't within the `<form>` element in your template, which they should be.

Comment: changed that, but now it reditects to create view again instead of going to created view. and It doesn't seem to have saved inputed data.

Comment: Because your data is presumably invalid, so it's showing the form again. You should be redisplaying the forms with their errors.

Comment: Now I come to look at your code again, I see that you are doing some very very strange things in your JS. Use a formset, since displaying multiple instances of a form is exactly what they are for.

Comment: why is it invalid? its just name and image. It should be any name and image right? yea I will change that to formset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82497/discussion-between-vato-and-daniel-roseman).

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do it is by making ajax request when you push the submit button.
Considering you have a form 'voteForm', try loading this form using django's inbuilt template as: 
{{voteForm.as_p}}

This will create your form for, which you have already done.
Now when you press submit button, make an ajax request with your form data in it.
The ajax request will take your data to the form and reverts back with a response which you can use to further do the processing.
A quick example for ajax request would be:

```
    function youfunctionname()
        $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: $("#yourformname").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       alert(data);
                   }
                 });
  }
```

Comment: "The easiest way to do it is y making ajax request when you push the submit button" : err well, actually, no.

Comment: why not? @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Because 1. it's NOT the "easiest way" - adding an ajax submission just means more code - and 2. it wouldn't solve the OP's problem which his having calls to `form.save()` and `instance.save()` whatever the method instead of branching on `request.method` to only do the save part if it's a POST (cf Daniel Roseman's answer).